no sound in plist on mac
I'm not able in my plist of sync to make a beep when finished.
this my code of plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Crashed</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>launched.arubas.sync.red</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/usr/bin/printf &quot;\a&quot;;/usr/bin/printf &quot;\a&quot;;/usr/bin/printf &quot;\a&quot;;/system/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console /users/oscarristolfi/arubaredsync.log &amp; /usr/local/bin/rclone sync /users/oscarristolfi/documents aruba-s3:/timemachine/documents   -vv --transfers=8 --log-file /users/oscarristolfi/arubaredsync.log &amp; /usr/local/bin/rclone sync /users/oscarristolfi/redincontri aruba-s3:/timemachine/redincontri  -vv --log-file /users/oscarristolfi/arubaredsync.log;/usr/bin/printf &quot;\a&quot;;/usr/bin/printf &quot;\a&quot;;/usr/bin/printf &quot;\a&quot;;</string>
        <string>/Users/oscarristolfi/Desktop/sound.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/oscarristolfi/arubaredsync.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/oscarristolfi/arubaredsync.log</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1800</integer>
</dict>
</plist>



What exactly are you attempting to do?  How are you running this, as a LaunchAgent or LaunchDaemon?  How is it failing?  What parts, if any, work?

~/Desktop is a protected folder.  Why are you keeping this script there?

The beep usually is done by Terminal. Launchd agents/daemons run without Terminal, so there is nothing which can „beep“.
